# Get/Set Workflow Variable from uiTypeEditor

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I have created a custom ui editor to handle setting the value of a variable for my workflow. What I want to do is be able to get the value of any of the variables set for the workflow within the uieditor.

```
public class MyCustomEditor : UITypeEditor
{
   public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value){

       IWindowsFormsEditorService service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

       IBuildDefinition buildDefinition = (IBuildDefinition)provider.GetService(typeof(IBuildDefinition));

       // Variable set in the workflow metadata to use this ui editor
       MyCustomVariable variable = value as MyCustomVariable;

       // Tried getting it from the Process Parameters but the only thing in there was BuildSettings
       var processParms = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(buildDefinition.ProcessParameters);

       object obj;
       processParms.TryGetValue("BuildSettings", out obj);
       BuildSettings buildSettings = obj as BuildSettings;

       // I want to be able to access other variable for the workflow, everything above works. But MyCustomVariable is set in the Metadata to use this editor. I want to get the value of another variable in the workflow as well

      return variable;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `BuildDefinition.Process.Parameters`? IIRC there is a subtle difference between that and `BuildDefinition.ProcessParameters`, in that the latter only has the ones overridden on the definition itself. Also the editor may be shown while editing a `BuildRequest`. You would also have to check the process parameters defined there.

Comment: I just tried to deserialize the WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(BuildDefinition.Process.Parameters) and I get an error `No matching constructor found on type. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct the type when attempting to use the following code.`

Comment: @mikez I see the xml value correctly, just need to know how I can get the current value?

Comment: Ok, I had to figure out if an argument/variable was defined in the process template at one point so I could override the default value. I just used `XDocument` to parse `BuildDefinition.Process.Parameters` and look for the existence of a specific element. Perhaps you could do the something similar, it's probably easy if the argument value is a primitive type, but it may be difficult if it's a custom type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, when I was looking at ProcessParameters, the build definition had not yet been saved so that's why I was only seeing 'BuildSettings' Once I deserialize them on a saved BuildDefinition, I could see all the variables.

```
var processParms = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(buildDefinition.ProcessParameters);

object obj;
processParms.TryGetValue("MyOtherVariable", out obj);
MyOtherVariable myOtherVariable = obj as MyOtherVariable;
```